# Get float value from NSData bytes

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata

how can I write this

```
float value = *(float *)[data bytes];
```

in swift?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The corresponding Swift code is

```
let value = UnsafePointer<Float>(data.bytes).memory
```

which – as your Objective-C code – assumes that the `NSData`
objects has (at least) 4 bytes, representing a floating point value
in host byte order.

- `UnsafePointer<Float>(..)` corresponds to the `(float *)` cast.
- `.memory` corresponds to the dereferencing operator `*`.

An alternative is

```
var value : Float = 0
data.getBytes(&value, length: sizeofValue(value))
```

Comment: You saved my day!! Thanks a billion.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are there any memory management issues we should be aware of here? Or will the ref counting take care of this?

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz: What memory management issues do you have in mind? The bytes are *copied* into the `value` variable, and `struct Float` is a value type, not a reference type.

Comment: Just that, I was curious to know if it was a heap pointer as opposed to a COW object. I assumed COW, but always safe to ask...